# how to parse array from json_dcode?

Tags: php, arrays, json

please help me with this json_decode array. this is my first time using this function. i want to echo the array but its keep showing error.
here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
$json = file_get_contents('http://sippadu.dpmptsp.sidoarjokab.go.id/bppt/int/m_tracking_qrcode.jsp?idtrack=08112017N1N083150');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo "Izin:".$obj->izin."<br>";
echo "Nama:". $obj->nama;

?>
```

this is output form json_decode im using print_r:

```
stdClass Object ( [records] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [izin] => (N08) Surat Izin Usaha Perdagangan (SIUP) [nama] => CV TIRTO MULYO [status] => Izin Anda sudah selesai. ) ) )
```

the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nama in /storage/ssd4/441/3008441/public_html/asd.php on line 7
```

please help, i just follow this instruction in other stackoverflow post. but my result false, thanks

Comment: Try to get this value using array from `json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the print_r produced an array of objects. So you need to access that array first before going ahead with `nama` and `izin`

It should be `$obj['records'][0]->izin` and `$obj['records'][0]->nama`

Comment: its still error using $obj['records']->izin :(   @cyberrspiritt

Comment: Edited my answer